# What is /?next=/ in url django?

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, unauthorized

I wonder why my url is http://localhost:8000/?next=/randomization/ when I directly type http://localhost:8000/randomization/ in the browser for an unauthorized user?

Comment: Presumably you've set the randomization view to login_required, and also set `LOGIN_URL` to `/`, which would be a strange thing to do.

Comment: thanks for replying. In fact, I use django-session-timeout to autologout user after time of inactivity. To implement this app, I need to set LOGIN_URL in settings.py and I want user to be redirected to home page after logout...

Answer (score 5):

The `/?next=/` will redirect to the page, after a user has logged in

Comment: Do you happen to know where in the source code Django parses the `next` query parameter?

Comment: @S.B

auth/__init__.py
`REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME = "next"`

django.contrib.auth.views.py

Answer (score 0):

`/?next=/`:

- shows the page redirected to after login.
- happens if you tries to open the page needed login without login.

For example, if you tries to open Django Admin home page below without login:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/
```

Then, you are redirected to Django Admin login page with `/?next=/admin/` as shown below, then if you successfully log in:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
```

Then, you are redirected to Django Admin home page below:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/
```